# DDD - DomainDrivenDesign and parsing date

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I want when I get value for `StatusDate` to automatically parse it and populate also `StatusDateFormatted`

example:

```
 public string StatusDate
        {
            get
            {
               return DateParser(StatusDate);
            }

        }

        public DateTime? StatusDateFormatted { get; set; }

        public string DateParser(string date)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(date))
            {
                DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.MinValue;
                DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                        System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate);
                if (parsedDate != DateTime.MinValue)
                {
                    StatusDateFormatted = parsedDate;
                }
            }
            return date;
        }
```

But if I remove seter from StatusDate (string), then I cant populate it ona service side, because it is a read-only property.
What I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged the question with DDD - you probably got it wrong if you want to follow tactical design patterns.

`StatusDate` is most likely a Value Object and not an entity. Value objects should be:

- constructed atomically
- immutable
- be equals to a value object of the same type if it holds the same properties

Therefore, if modeled as a Value Object you should do the validation for being a parseable date in the constructor and throw an exception or return an error value if this is not the case. Furthermore remove the setter and implement equals/hashcode. Lastly offer the "parsed" or "formatted" Status date via method on the Value Object.

If it changes, the Value Object as a whole must be replaced (immutability)

Answer (score 0):

Your code, as written, would cause a *Stack Overflow* exception, but that aside, it is important to separate the workflows for reading and writing properties.

Consider the following:

```
public DateTime? StatusDateFormatted { get; private set; }

// Backing field for your persisted property
private string statusDate;

public string StatusDate 
{
    get { return statusDate; }
    set {
        // Each time the value is set, attempt to parse it and cache the value
        DateTime parsedDate;
        bool parsed = DateTime.TryParseExact(
            date, 
            "yyyyMMdd", 
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, 
            out parsedDate);

        // Clear the value in case the date cannot be parsed
        StatusDateFormatted = null;
        if (parsed)
        {
            // Cache the parsed value
            StatusDateFormatted = parsedDate;
        }        
    }
}
```